# Disappearing independent varible in vegan::Adonis output

Tags: vegan, multivariate-testing

I am running a PERMANOVA using adonis2 from the vegan package. I have 52 vegetation plots within 4 study areas. I am interested in how exclosure, fire, and bear presence is impacting these vegetation plots. I also want to include a random effect for study area. All of the plots with bears are in Study Area A or B, and all of the plots without bears are in Study Area C or D. The other treatments (exclosure, fire) were applied randomly across al study areas. I understand adonis2 will not permit random effects explicitly, so I put it first in the formula list since order matters in the adonis2 function.

The following code returns an output with the full expected list of independent variables:

```
> adonis2(formula = comp[ ,10:22] ~ FenceStatus + WolfStatus + FireStatus, 
+        data = comp,
+        method = "euc")
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

adonis2(formula = comp[, 10:22] ~ FenceStatus + WolfStatus + FireStatus, data = comp, method = "euc")
             Df SumOfSqs      R2        F Pr(>F)    
FenceStatus   1     4435 0.00812   6.3237  0.003 ** 
BearStatus    1    26352 0.04823  37.5756  0.001 ***
FireStatus    1   299575 0.54831 427.1694  0.001 ***
Residual    308   216001 0.39534                    
Total       311   546362 1.00000                    
---
```

However, adding in the StudyArea term causes the Fire variable to disappear from the results list:

```
> adonis2(formula = comp[ ,10:22] ~ StudyArea + FenceStatus + BearStatus + FireStatus, 
+         data = comp,
+         method = "euc")
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

adonis2(formula = comp[, 10:22] ~ StudyArea + FenceStatus + BearStatus + FireStatus, data = comp, method = "euc")
             Df SumOfSqs      R2       F Pr(>F)    
StudyArea     3   137664 0.25196  68.271  0.001 ***
FenceStatus   1     4435 0.00812   6.598  0.003 ** 
FireStatus    1   198587 0.36347 295.452  0.001 ***
Residual    306   205677 0.37645                   
Total       311   546362 1.00000                   
---
```

Could this be because of the nested structure of BearStatus within Study Area? Since all of the plots with bears are in Study Area A or B, and all of the plots without bears are in Study Area C or D A or B, and all of the plots without bears are in Study Area C or D.

Any help is appreciated. I can provide a reprod dataset if needed, but I thought maybe it would be obvious to someone with just seeing my output.